# ion-Auth codeigniter multi page registration form

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I would like to create a registration form using Ion-Auth, but cannot seem to find any tutorial that is specific. After creating the form I would like the form to be a multi page / multiple step form which stores data in a session and passing on to the next function and the submission will happen at the final step.

Doing something like the following, the only difference is the data from previous form will be passed on to the next function using sessions, I am not sure how to do this passing using sessions, the submission will happen on the final step:

```
    public function submit (){

    if ($this->input->post('submit-1')) //Use unique names for each submit 
    button value on the forms

    {

    //validate and save form data to database


    $this->load->view('author/submit_step2');

    }

    elseif ($this->input->post('submit-2'))

    {

    //validate and save form data to database

    $this->load->view ('author/submit_step3');

    }


    {

    //validate and save form data to database


    $this->load->view('author/success');

    }

    else

    {

    $this->load->view('author/submit_step1');
```

Comment: Take a look on this link https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I need a step by step tutorial on how to create a registration form in ion-auth first. Thank you